# Fail to download csv with read.table(url()) from github

Tags: r

The following command failed to download a [csv file](https://github.com/jeanpat/pyFISH/blob/master/GUI/karyotyper/example%20classification/source%20data/features/jp-Jpp48-1-DAPI.csv):

```
read.table(url('https://github.com/jeanpat/pyFISH/blob/master/GUI/karyotyper/example  classification/source data/features/jp-Jpp48-1-DAPI.csv'))

Erreur dans open.connection(file, "rt") : impossible d'ouvrir la connexion
De plus : Message d'avis :
In open.connection(file, "rt") : schéma URL non supporté
```

Is it a github or a R issue ?

Thank you

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299220/access-a-url-and-read-data-with-r

Comment: But I think https requests are not supported from `url`. You might need `library(RCurl)` and there then the `getURL` command.

Comment: Yes, if you replace https with http it should work.

Comment: I am not sure if github supports unencrypted connections. Of course that would be the easiest way.

Comment: @juba, replacing https with http won't work with Github, especially not if one is linking to the "display" page and not the "raw" file. See the answers at the linked duplicate question.