# How to Read a .csv file from url

Tags: r, shiny

I have successfully developed a Shiny Application for sentiment analysis. When I deployed the application, it was not working. After going through the code I found that my code is referring to the files(emotions.csv.gz,subjectivity.csv.gz) which are located in my system. That could be the reason why the application is not working because on server its not able to find these particular files. Is there be any method to read these files directly from the url where they are present, so that there will be no system dependencies?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299220/access-a-url-and-read-data-with-r  You can run something like `X <- read.csv(url("http://some.where.net/data/foo.csv"))`

Comment: I have done this but its giving me a warning message"Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string"

Comment: that's an issue with the data or with the remote web server mangling the data in transit. we can't help you with that w/o the URL to the data.

Comment: Thanks for response but I found the solution, I just put two files in my folder of application so that it can easily available to the server.