# R: "read" a txt file from a URL

Tags: r, url, text, import, download

I  am interested to see if it is possible to directly load (into R) txt file from a url instead of downloading it and then importing it.

I came across this post over here: [Access a URL and read Data with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299220/access-a-url-and-read-data-with-r)

Apparently it is possible to do this with csv files. Is it possible to do the same thing for txt files?

I tried to adapt the code from this stackoverflow post for the following website: https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/MackeyGlass_t17.txt

```
myfile <- read.txt(url("https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/MackeyGlass_t17.txt"))
```

But it does not seem to be working.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is is not possible to directly load a txt file from a url into R?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `data.table` function `fread()` (one of the fastest functions for loading data):

```
library(data.table)
#Load
myfile <- fread("https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/MackeyGlass_t17.txt")
```

Output (some rows):

```
head(myfile)
            V1
1:  0.12206400
2:  0.04719682
3: -0.01833035
4: -0.08194958
5: -0.13422158
6: -0.18542675
```

You can wrap it as dataframe using `as.data.frame()` or:

```
#Load 2
myfile <- fread("https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/MackeyGlass_t17.txt",data.table = F)
```

Comment: Related to `fread`, `read_lines` from `library(readr)` or `library(tidyverse)` is also a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `read.txt` doesn't exist.

```
?read.txt
```

> No documentation for ‘read.txt’ in specified packages and libraries:
> you could try ‘??read.txt’

It should be `read.table` (no need of any packages)

```
myfile <- read.table(url("https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/MackeyGlass_t17.txt"))
```

-output

```
dim(myfile)
#[1] 10000     1
head(myfile)
#           V1
#1  0.12206400
#2  0.04719682
#3 -0.01833035
#4 -0.08194958
#5 -0.13422158
#6 -0.18542675
```